# How much in depth should I cover Python?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I'm an undergrad who's studying electronics and fields like data sciences and mostly computing seem most interesting to me but have in-depth knowledge in neither. I learnt basic python last winter vacations and have built on it since then. I'm not too sure how further I should keep doing this and hence wanted to know how beneficial is python to an electronics student (keeping my interests in mind) and should I keep adding to my knowledge?

Comment: Hi 4manshenoy and welcome to scicomp!  While your question is indeed interesting, this really isn't the right forum for this kind of question.  You may have better luck in another forum such as Academia.SE.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the basics of Python, you should just try to get your hands dirty using some well known/documented Python libraries for the type of work you want to do.

If you find you don't understand how to use certain features of the libraries due to inadequate knowledge in Python, just study up on those features and then get back to working with the library. Outside of this, it will be hard for any of us to comment on how much more you should learn Python since we don't really know where your skills are at. Good luck.